# Want to compare alphanumeric values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to compare alphanumeric values in sql server database and select the values in specific range.

For ex: Grade of employee is in range of A1 to A20 and I want to select all employees greater than A5 grade.

```
EMP_ID     GRADE 
1111       A01
2222       A15
3333       A09
4444       A09
5555       UC
6666       A14
7777       A15
8888       TRN
9999       A04
4242       A14
1212       TRN
1515       A12
5541       UC
5563       A05


These are sample values. When I run the select query without using 
predicate "AND LEFT(GRADE,1) = 'A' ", it is only retrieving values up 
to A6,   where as it should retrieve up to A15 which is maximum in current scenario.  

Where as after using the predicate  "AND LEFT(GRADE,1) = 'A' " I am getting  
correct values i.e. up to A15 in this same scenario.  

GRADE column can have any number of repeated entries. All of them needs to be   retrieved.  
Can you please tell best possible to do this without using predicate  
"AND LEFT(GRADE,1) = 'A' "?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the integer part and use that as a filter:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME 
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(GRADE,2,LEN(GRADE)-1) AS INT) > 5
```

Comment: but now this column also has some 'UC' and 'TRN' values that is of string type and while the above CAST tries to convert it to INT it throws an error.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'RN' to data type int.
can u please tell how to handle this error?
@jpw

Comment: Also it is displaying values in range A6 to A7 while values A8 to A16 are also present

Comment: @Shardul The question didn't indicate that there could be values other than those in the range A1-A20. You can make sure that only values starting with A are selected by adding another predicate tp the where clause: `AND LEFT(GRADE,1) = 'A'`

Comment: @Shardul As for your assertion that values A8-A16 are not displayed (at least I think that is what you mean, it's not all clear to me), I can not recreate this - I get the expected values in my test.

Comment: After adding the predicate the query is working fine now.
But if I don't use this predicate and if my GRADE column contains values  'A1-A20','UC','TRN' then the query is fetching records upto A6 only.
Please tell me if you are able to recreate this.
Thanks a lot for your help.@jpw

Comment: @Shardul Is `A1-A20` one or several values? I'm afraid I don't quite understand the issue. Could you update your original question and add in some sample data and desired output?

Comment: @Shardul I can't recreate your problem. When I run the query as `SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(GRADE,2,LEN(GRADE)-1) AS INT) > 5 AND LEFT(GRADE,1) = 'A'` I get the 7 expected rows starting  `A15,A09,A09,A14,A15,A14,A12`.

Comment: Please try it without using "AND LEFT(GRADE,1) = 'A' ", that's where I am facing problem.
Try This :
SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(GRADE,2,LEN(GRADE)-1) AS INT) > 5 
@jpw

Comment: @Shardul Without the extra predicate the query will fail with a conversion error (which would be expected), but since you want the values of the rows starting with A I don't see why you want to remove the condition?

Comment: No I don't want to remove that condition just wanted to know how can we handle such errors and make code efficient so that it will not throw error if by mistake we forgot to add any extra predicate.
Anyways thanks for your efforts and help.@jpw